# Phonegap caching Json data on local device

Tags: json, caching, cordova

since the last weeks i was diving into the mobile app developement. What i want to do is to use Phonegap in order to cache Json-Files to have a WebApp working even if there is no wifi or internet-connection.
I'm very much puzzled. I've read many aproaches concerning offline-caching.
But what i do not understand is, how to use for example cached Json-Files to render my web-app in offline mode.

**I always thought it could work as follows:**

Let's say i have a website, which is responisve. The content of this site is generated dynamically based upon Json-Data.

Now i want to bring this website to a mobile device.
I start with Phonegap. I write my first simple app  with a webview or a InAppBrowser, which holds my website. 
Now i want to make this App being able to work even if offline based upon the cached Json-Data. 
This is where i'm hanging in the air. I do not know any further. 
Do i request the Json-Data and store this data into the local filesystem of my device with the PhoneGap File-Api? And how do use this data in order to build my layout.
As far as did understand, i have PhoneGap as a container, which making the bridge between my response (HTML5, CCS, JS) WebSite and native functions.
So what i do understand is, that i can load my website within a PhonGap container and it pretty much looks like an App. But when i'm offline i have to have data cached. Most important the Json-Data, on which the markup is based upon. How can i load this Json-Data from my local device and use this data to render?
Today i was building a simple App, using PhoneGap with an InAppBrowser. Then i've found no tutorial how to cache the Json-Data, which was pulled by my responsive website. I could see this data has been used (via Fiddler as reverseproxy). So this data must be transferred to the InAppBrowser. I thought i mistunderstood something. maybe i have to include everything into the index.html (i'm using eclipse and phonegap and android).
Can anyone tell on a simple example how i can call my website, cache the Json-Data (large Files, up to 100MB on the local device with PhoneGap File-Api) and use this Json-File to render my WebSite when offline? 
Is this somehwo possible?

---

**Update:**
I found this post on the internet, which can be adjusted, to fulfill my needs: [here](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/1/19/Downloading-files-to-a-PhoneGap-application--Part-1)
The code from this example, is this code from the index.html or is this code used within the website? Do i have to include the cordova.js into my website, too?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you can store your JSON Data into HTML5 localstorage and make it Offline. But here localstorage gives size limit upto 5MB.

But as you said you are working with large data then,
You can do it via this approach:

- Create phonegap custom plugin for handling all webservice calls
- Using this plugin also store JSON data into native storage database (there
  is no size limit cause you are using device storage)

So, there will be no ajax calls on your HTML code instead of Plugin is handling it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This approach is something i could try, but i've found something here: [link](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/1/19/Downloading-files-to-a-PhoneGap-application--Part-1). My Problem was this: When i'm loading my WebSite within an InAppBrowser or WebView how would it be possible to rebuild the markup in offline-mode based upon the cached Json-Data. As for now i know that you can write a SPA with everything in it (JS, AJAX, CSS etc.). So now i have full control over the markup. And can rebuild it with my cached Json-Data.

Answer (score 0):

you can save json into filesystem... and you doesn't need LocalStorage or DB.

Comment: You're right. I've managed to download a load of round about 130MB Json-Data in order to parse it and build my markup when needed (based upon userinteraction). I'm storing the data on the sdcard - when my app goes offline - the data from sdcard is pulled otherwhise ajax-request's playing the game. What helped veeery much was the usage of jQuery Deferred and Promises to not run into spaghetty code with Phonegap.